# Complex multiple queries in mongoose with $or

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to find a way to get myself a clean as possible code for using multiple complex queries.

I have 2 documents in MongoDB.
First one is followers and second one is events.

First query: Get all the followers from a specific user.
Second query: Get all the events from all those followers and sort them by date.

I have no idea how to do the second query.

Maybe something like this:

```
Event.find({ "$or" : [
                        {
                            'userId': followers[0].id,
                        },
                        {
                            'userId': followers[1].id,
                        },
                        {
                            'userId': followers[2].id,
                        },
                        ]});
```

But that doesn't feel a very clean code to me.

Comment: I think what you require is the [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator; `var userIds = [followers[0].id, followers[1].id, followers[2].id]; Event.find({ 'userId': { $in: userIds } }, function(err, result){ ... });`

Comment: @chridam Looks like an "answer" to me. Especially if you can explain the relation of `$or` to `$in`. I would simply though: `{  "userId": { "$in": followers.map(function(follower) { return follower.id })) } }`

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for the suggestion, the `map` function is more preferrable in this case methinks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you require is the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator. The [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator only takes one index whilst the [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or) operator takes more (one per clause). The [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-versus-in) also explicitly states that:

> When using $or with  that are equality checks for the
>   value of the same field, use the $in operator instead of the $or
>   operator.

You can modify your query as follows:

```
var userIds = [followers[0].id, followers[1].id, followers[2].id]; 
Event.find({ 'userId': { $in: userIds } }, function(err, result){ ... });
```

Or as Neil Lunn suggested, another workaround would be to use the native map method to produce an array of the required user ids:

```
Event.find({
     "userId": {
          "$in": followers.map(function (follower){
               return follower.id
           }))
     }
}, function(err, result){ ... });
```

Comment: Not actually true that multiple indexes "will" be used as the optimizer will clearly work out that a single index can be used since it's all about the same field. The point is that `$or` and `$in` are really the same form when used with a simple value or regular expression on the same field. So `$in` is to `$or` as `$all` is to `$and`.

Comment: @NeilLunn You are absolutely correct, will also point out that the query optimizer handles `$in` more efficiently.